# How can I build a left nav using react router and history in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to load a left nav using ReactRouter 1.1 and `History.js`
This is my list of routes:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRedirect to="/stories" />
      <Route path="/stories" component={StoriesContainer} />
      <Route path="/stories/new" component={NewStory} />
      <Route path="/stories/:storyId" component={StoryContainer}>
        <Route path="overview" component={XStoryOverviewContainer} />
        <Route path="messages" component={XMessageListContainer} />
        <Route path="settings" component={XStorySettingsContainer} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Then I have StoryContainer, which contains a left nav and a list of children that are nested in the routes file (please notice that the left nav was not meant for the entire application, only in StoryContainer and children components). The StoryContainer loads the left nav as follows:

```
<div>
  <StoryNavigationCard
    items={navigation}
    selectedItemKey={this.state.navigationKey}
    onOptionSelected={path => this._navigationKeyChanged(path)}>
    </StoryNavigationCard>
     {
      this.props.children
    }
</div>

  _navigationKeyChanged(path: string) {
    this.history.pushState(null, path);
  }
```

ATTENTION to the way I set the new path (using History). 
Now this is my navigation card.

```
 const React = require('React');

type Props = {
  items: Array<Object>,
  selectedItemKey: string,
  onOptionSelected: () => void,
};

type State = {
  selectedItemKey: string,
};

class StoryNavigationCard extends React.Component<void, Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedItemKey: props.selectedItemKey};
  }

  PropTypes: Props;

  render(): ReactElement {

    const navigationItems = this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <CardSection
        onClick={() => {
          this.props.onOptionSelected(item.path);
          this.setState({selectedItemKey: item.key});
        }}
        key={item.key}>
        {item.label}
      </CardSection>
    ));

    return (
      <Card>
        {navigationItems}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

ATENTION to the onClick button. I'm setting the state of the parent given the state of the child. That's not the way react works and how it should be done, but I couldn't find another way to update the state of the item than doing that.
In a few words, the problem I'm facing is the following:
File Routes has a Component X with components A, B and C that are nested.
The component X has a left nav, which has the list of options "a", "b", and "c".
Either if the user clicks on one of the options, or goes to the url "x/a", "x/b", or "x/c", I want to be able to load the component properly (set the proper value of the selected option the left nav, load the right component in the view).

I hope this question helps other people that are also asking the same question online, I couldn't find a solution for this that seem appropiate.

Comment: It's not clear to me what behaviour you're expecting. When you say "left nav", I think a menu fixed to the left composed of anchor tags to various links, which has nothing whatsoever to do with `react-router`. Why are you using `pushState` instead of a `Link` component?

Comment: It *has* to do with react router. See history mixin: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGES.md#state-mixin.

Comment: The problem starts when the user clicks on an item of the left nav. I use history.pushState, which changes the url. React router catches the url, routes it to the react component that matches the url.
In this case, let's say '/stories/:storyId/overview'. XStoryOverviewContainer will automatically render as child of XStoryOverviewContainer. But the question is how do I know what is the current selected option from the class? I can't mark the selected option in the nav because of that.

Comment: Why aren't you using `<Link>` in your nav?

Comment: Again, I asked why you are using `pushState` instead of `Link` (as @DavidL.Walsh also just mentioned), since everything you have mentioned is build in to it. Even if you weren't using `Link` to add a highlighting class and provide the appropriate history method, an anchor tag would also work. Why `pushState`? Is there a piece of architecture you left out?

Comment: I've just tried ReactRouter.Link and it works in the same way as history.pushState. thanks!.
I think the only problem I'm facing is that when the user clicks the link, the page redirects properly (the url changes and the child container is the right one), but the current selected element in the nav is wrong.

Comment: The active class `Link` assigns is based on the URL provided in the `to` prop. Can you provide the code you're using for the links and which ones don't work?